# What is the "sys.stdout.write()" equivalent in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, stdout

As seen in Python, what is the `sys.stdout.write()` equivalent in Ruby?

Comment: it will be good if you explain what `sys.stdout.write()` does in python

Comment: @Salil: It writes a string to the standard output.

Answer (score 51):

In Ruby, you can access standard out with `$stdout` or `STDOUT`. So you can use the [write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-write) method like this:

```
$stdout.write 'Hello, World!'
```

or equivalently:

```
STDOUT.write 'Hello, World!'
```

`$stdout` is a actually a global variable whose default value is `STDOUT`.

You could also use `puts`, but I think that is more analogous to python's `print`.

Answer (score 7):

[`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005954) (or [`print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005952) if you don't want a newline (`\n`) automatically appended).

Answer (score 6):

```
puts "Hello, world!"
```

or `print` - because it buffered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner for both writing and reading to/from stdin and stdout.

```
$ ruby -e '$stdout.write "hi\n" '
hi

$ echo "somestring" | ruby -e 'p  $stdin.read'
"somestring\n"

$ echo "somestring" | ruby -e 'puts   $stdin.read'
somestring
```